# how to improve simple dijkstra algorithm for shortest path routing

Tags: java, shortest-path, dijkstra, mininet

I am trying to simulate SDN based shortest path routing using Dijkstra algorithm. Is there anything that I can improve in the following code ? I am using Floodlight controller and trying to optimize routing between two hosts.

Here is my sample code:

```
public static Graph calculateShortestPathFromSource(Graph graph, Node source) 
{
    source.setDistance(0);
    Set<Node> settledNodes = new HashSet<>();
    Set<Node> unsettledNodes = new HashSet<>();
    unsettledNodes.add(source);
    while (unsettledNodes.size() != 0) {
        Node currentNode = getLowestDistanceNode(unsettledNodes);
        unsettledNodes.remove(currentNode);
        for (Map.Entry < Node, Integer> adjacencyPair:
          currentNode.getAdjacentNodes().entrySet()) {
            Node adjacentNode = adjacencyPair.getKey();
            Integer edgeWeight = adjacencyPair.getValue();
            if (!settledNodes.contains(adjacentNode)) {
                CalculateMinimumDistance(adjacentNode, edgeWeight, currentNode);
                unsettledNodes.add(adjacentNode);
            }
        }
        settledNodes.add(currentNode);
    }
    return graph;
}

/**
 * Function to get minimum distance.
 * Source: Baeldung (www.baeldung.com/java-dijkstra)
 */ 
private static Node getLowestDistanceNode(Set < Node > unsettledNodes) 
{
    Node lowestDistanceNode = null;
    int lowestDistance = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (Node node: unsettledNodes) {
        int nodeDistance = node.getDistance();
        if (nodeDistance < lowestDistance) {
            lowestDistance = nodeDistance;
            lowestDistanceNode = node;
        }
    }
    return lowestDistanceNode;
}

/** 
 * Function to get minimum distance.
 * Source: Baeldung (www.baeldung.com/java-dijkstra)
 */
private static void CalculateMinimumDistance(Node evaluationNode, Integer edgeWeigh, Node sourceNode) 
{
    Integer sourceDistance = sourceNode.getDistance();
    if (sourceDistance + edgeWeigh < evaluationNode.getDistance()) 
    {
        evaluationNode.setDistance(sourceDistance + edgeWeigh);
        LinkedList<Node> shortestPath = new LinkedList<>(sourceNode.getShortestPath());
        shortestPath.add(sourceNode);
        evaluationNode.setShortestPath(shortestPath);
    }
}
```

Comment: what kind of improvement are you looking for?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Unless you specify what you consider unsatisfactory in the behavior of this code, it's not clear what the problem is. In case if you're just looking for any hypothetical improvement of this Dijkstra-algorithm implementation from Baeldung, then it rather a question for [*Code Review Stack Exchange*](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)